# How to set a build path from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath

In Eclipse, I can right click on the project and then click on `Build Path` and `Use as a source folder`. How can I do this from terminal?

For context, I have a maven project in Eclipse which I can run properly if I do the above mentioned things. I want to do the same thing from terminal. What is the command to do this from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps If you prefer to add some external folder as source folder through the terminal way. Eclipse treats the following folders as source folders by default in case of maven project:

1. src/main/java
2. src/main/resources
3. src/test/java
4. src/test/resources

This case applicable even when you are run the maven project through the command line interface from the project root. If you like to add any other folder as source apart from the above list, which can be easily achieved through the **build-helper-maven-plugin**. Just create the required source folder through the terminal and then add the folder entry in the below maven plugin.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>**some source directory you prefer**</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

[for more about the plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: My problem is if I do the steps mentioned in eclipse, I can run the code in Eclipse. If I don't do the steps mentioned, then I get this error `Error: Could not find or load main class`. In terminal I get the same error because I haven't set my buildpath (and use as a source folder). How do I do that?

Comment: I hope you are trying to run the java class manually which requires a huge effort of setting up the classpath with the `java -cp`, I suggest running your application as an executable jar. You can configure the maven pom to build your application as an executable jar. you can [refer](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) for more details